# How my rasa chatbot can modify parameters on Rshiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, chatbot, rasa

I have created a chatbot with rasa and on the other hand I have a Rshiny dashboard with charts.

My goal is to have the chatbot be able to change the charts when I ask it to.

But the problem is that I have little experience with rasa and I haven't found any way to allow this. Do you have any ideas?